# Alternating downloads with php

Tags: php

I have this code, that working fine :

```
$files = "files1.rar";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-rar-compressed');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your_download.rar" ');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($files));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($files);
exit;
```

But I would like to add some other files, maybe with an array like :

```
$files=array('1'=>"files1.rar", '2'=>"files2.rar");
```

With a download link like download.php?docid=1

And an expired date based on the file's upload + one week.

Thanks

Comment: You can only transfer one file at a time. Zip all the files you want to offer as a single download and then make the zip available.

Comment: In fact I've already found an old code picked here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1878235/6832070

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the download, the best way - in my opinion - is to create a zip file on the server and download this one.

From my point of view, it is not possibe to download files on the way you have choose.

Here is a link to the php dokumentation  on the Zip process in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/de/zip.examples.php

On [Git](https://github.com/michael-mammut/imageresizer/blob/master/controller/CompressingHandler.php), there is an example.